# Размещение чего либо в форме или на картинке и т.д.

Tags: html, css, form

Всем привет, всегда хотел понять как же все таки размещаются какие либо объекты внутри формы или на картинке средствами css.

Примером простая форма ВК http://i7.pixs.ru/storage/7/1/1/1png_9284714_10344711.png (две картинки внутри формы), или вот такое наложение на картинку http://i7.pixs.ru/storage/7/2/0/1png_7469591_10344720.png (похоже блок div).

Возможно оно не взаимосвязано но все же, кто может в общих чертах пояснить или дать линк на статью, потому как я не смог сформулировать правильный запрос в гугл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на первой картинке объект только выглядит как поле формы. Само поле лишено оформления. Кнопки рядом размещены как любые другие элементы. На второй же картинке обыкновенный фон.

Comment: а есть какие-то статьи которые рассказывают как это делать?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru — целый сайт таких статей :)

Comment: Что ж спасибо)